# How to combine must and must_not in elasticsearch with same field

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana

i have elasticsearch 6.8.8, just for an example of my question. I want to create a query that gets me document with "Test" field with value "1", and i don't want to get "Test" field with value of "3", i know that i could write just the first expression without 3 and it will give me one document with value of "1". But i want to know, is there any way, that i can use must and must_not in the same time, on the same field and getting just the value of "1"?

I wrote this basic example to know what i mean:

```
{
"from": 0,
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "attributes",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "attributes.key": {
                                            "query": "Test"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "attributes.value": {
                                            "query": "1"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "must_not": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "attributes.key": {
                                            "query": "Test"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "attributes.value": {
                                            "query": "3"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I use attributes as nested field with key-value field that use mapping as string type.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to leave out `attributes.key:Test` in the `must_not` because it filters out all `Test`s:

```
GET combine_flat/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {}, 
      "path": "attributes",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "attributes.key": {
                        "query": "Test"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "attributes.value": {
                        "query": "1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "attributes.value": {
                        "query": "3"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tip: use `inner_hits` to just return the matched nested key-value pairs as opposed to the whole field.

Comment: Thank you. But i have a question, the must not, will filter out just "3" value for "Test" key? Or it will filter for "Test1" "Test2" keys too?

Comment: I mean if i add them, to the query. The "Test1" and "Test2"

Comment: Well you already specified `Test1` in the `must` so it'll filter out all other `key`s that don't match that. If you wanna force key-value pairs, you'll have to do a much of `bool-musts` within your main `bool-must`.